# Add values to NSMutabkeArray while saving to UserDefaults Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

```
let fpost = DataSevice.ds.REF_BASE.child("movies").childByAutoId()
fpost.setValue(post)

//store the array
var array = ["keys:"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
array.append(fpost.key)
print(array)
defaults.setValue(array, forKey: "myPosts")
defaults.synchronize()
```

In this code, every time a user posts, I want to add something to the array and then save it using UserDefaults. However, when I do this it only takes the most recent value and stores that into the array which doesn't show any other post key. How can i make it so it stores all values?

Comment: What is the value of `fpost.key`? Are you actually getting any valid data?

Are you running this only once? If you do, it would be natural to get only one key.

Comment: yes i am. It comes out to be a valid string so that is not the problem. Also different fPost values appear everytime i post so i want to add all those different post keys

Comment: So are you running this code in a callback? Because that would be the only way to ensure this code runs whenever you get a new key. Otherwise, you're just running it once, getting one single key and finishing.

Comment: Where does `DataService` come from?

Comment: DataService is a class i made to help fetch data from my database

Comment: Simply put, my question is how can i add a String to an NSMutableArray which is saved to UserDefaults

Comment: You should be able to do that using `array.append`. Isn't the first key getting added?